# iOS network issue. TLS Session cache loophole

Tags: ios, security, caching, ssl, https

I'm facing a security-related issue for my iOS application. I'm using HTTPS for all my network calls and the public certificate used is from Trusted Authority which is bundled in the application to prevent Main in the Middle Attack (ref: [Man in the middle attack - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)). I'm doing SSL Pinning (verifying the certificate from server in/before every network call) in Android it works perfectly fine, in iOS however there is a TLS Session Cache which cache the certificate validity after first network call.

For first network call the certificate validation part works fine, for 2nd call, cache is used by OS and I'm unable to verify the certificate. My QA team can easily attack and get all the data from the network call for 2nd and consecutive network calls. Here's the reference for [TLS Session Cache iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1727/_index.html). Seems like there's no way to clear the cache programmatically ref: [AdvancedURLConnections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Listings/Read_Me_About_AdvancedURLConnections_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009558-Read_Me_About_AdvancedURLConnections_txt-DontLinkElementID_24).

Changing query parameter doesn't help, I already tried that. Please provide iOS specific solution. I can't do encryption of my data for business reasons.

**EDIT:**
I'm using below mentioned method to verify my certificate. For first network call this method is called by the OS, for consecutive calls this method is not being called.

```
willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

My QA team simply does MiTM attack for every network call, they try to use their certificate and if for any network call I don't verify certificate then they can easily read the data. Because of cache I'm unable to verify my certificate.

Comment: I don't see how veriyfying the server certificate before every network call adds anything to security, nor how a TLS session cache can either prevent you verifying the certificate *or* compromise security. I'd like to see some details of how your QA team mounted their MITM attack. Perhaps @Bruno has something to add on these topics?

Comment: @Husyn - Like EJP, I'd like to hear a little more about the attack on the cache that leads to MitM. Is this the [triple handshake attack](http://secure-resumption.com/), or a a spin on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that this method will be called again if you switch your network. The response or result of the authentication is persistent for a session and as long as the session is valid, the connection is secured. So just rely on the framework's method and keep your communication secured :)